# Spring boot running too slow for postgres 9.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, hikaricp, postgres-9.6

i had one project with apache ninja using java 8 and postgres 9.6. I needed to migrate this to spring boot only. I am using spring boot 2.5.x. but when i configured this project it is running 10x slower than apache ninja. i found jdbc connection is taking too much time to acquire and execution.
in my apache project i was using

```
<dependency>
<groupId>postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

i was not able to use same in spring boot.

below is my pom.xml for spring boot

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.12</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

just help how can i fix it so it can perform at least same like apache ninja 10x faster.

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing with configuration and code this will be impossible to answer. The `exclusion` will do nothing here as HikariCP is already the default connection pool. So remove the exclude and the `com.zaxxer` dependency as those are already included.

Comment: thanks for your response i have provided more details in my answer.

Comment: Don't put additional details in an answer, instead edit your question. One thing is why are you not using the default SPring Boot auto-configuration which does optimizations for JPA as well. If you don't have multipe datasources use the default configuration. Next what configuration did you use previously as you should move that to SPring Boot (the number of connections, timeouts etc.). Finally don't use a `connectionTestQuery` as Hikari will automatically use the JDBC 4connection validation which is better.